# How execute EdgeOS crontab jobs

Tags: crontab

I have this in `sudo crontab -l`

```
0 17 * * 1-5 ipsec start
0 06 * * 1-5 ipsec stop
```

The commands `sudo ipsec start` and `sudo ipsec stop` work splendidly. But the scheduled jobs are not executing.  What else is needed beside the crontab settings?

Comment: Is this a `root` cron?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes